# AS3 - How to properly stop player with hitTestObject and restrict player's movement based on colliding area?

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest

I have two issues with collision, the player can glitch through the object when pressing the moving keys multiple times and both the player's `x` and `y` movement would stop once touching any side of the object. It should only stop `x` or `y` depending on which side it's touching.

While it touches the left/right sides of the bounding box, it should still be able to move up and down. While it touches the top/bottom sides of the bounding box, it should be able to move side to side.

My movement code inside Player class `ENTER_FRAME`:

```
private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    _vx = 0;
    _vy = 0;

    if (isRight)
    {
        _vx = 5;
    }

    if (isLeft)
    {
        _vx = -5;
    }

    if (isUp)
    {
        _vy = -5;
    }

    if (isDown)
    {
        _vy = 5;
    }

    x += _vx;
    y += _vy;

}
```

My hitTestObject code in CollisionBase class `ENTER_FRAME` (Base Class for `MovieClips`):

```
private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    if (MovieClip(parent).player.collisionArea.hitTestObject(this))
    {
        if (MovieClip(parent).player.isLeft)
        {
            MovieClip(parent).player.x -= MovieClip(parent).player._vx;
        }

        if (MovieClip(parent).player.isRight)
        {
            MovieClip(parent).player.x -= MovieClip(parent).player._vx;
        }

        if (MovieClip(parent).player.isUp)
        {
            MovieClip(parent).player.y -= MovieClip(parent).player._vy;
        }

        if (MovieClip(parent).player.isDown)
        {
            MovieClip(parent).player.y -= MovieClip(parent).player._vy;
        }
    }
}
```

`FLA` file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k5dlxrsnvbrmtke/Subject.zip?dl=0

The `FLA` file includes a player and a bed for it to collide with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your game design is not well structured. You should have one single `ENTER_FRAME` for the game logic. Instead of that, you have one `ENTER_FRAME` for the player, one `ENTER_FRAME` to swap children, and one `ENTER_FRAME` in every obstacle. This design give you more than one headache and will put the performance of your game on the floor.

To fix the problem with the `hitTest` do the next things:

Put this code in the `CollisionBase` `Class`:

```
private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{

    var player:MovieClip = MovieClip(this.parent).player;

    if (player.collisionArea.hitTestObject(this)) player.collision = true;
}
```

Add this property to the `Player` `Class`:

```
private var _collision:Boolean = false;

public function set collision(value:Boolean):void{
    _collision = value;
}
```

And next, add these lines at the beginning of the `onEnterFrame` function:

```
private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{

    if(_collision){

        x -= _vx;
        y -= _vy;

        _collision = false;

       return;

    }

    _vx = 0;
    _vy = 0;

    if (isRight)
    {
    ....
```

The problem has been fixed, but now your player going to flicker when hits an obstacle. This happens because the player `ENTER_FRAME` moves the player, and then other `ENTER_FRAME` checks the collision (in `CollisionBase.class`) and in the next cycle of the player `ENTER_FRAME` the player does a step back. If you have a single `ENTER_FRAME`, such thing never happens.

I propose you other alternative. Look at this example and look how it is made, maybe it give you some ideas ;)

[Download the example](http://xprimiendo.com/examples/FLASH/HitTestGame.zip)

Comment: The collision seems to be working well on the example file. However it does not use the base class for obstacle and instead uses mainclass. Would you please update the example so the movement and collision codes work inside player class and obstacle base class instead of using main class? I'm sorry but I'm confused and can't get it to work, thank you!

Comment: If you want you can have a `class` for the obstacles, but if you look into the example, I've tried to explain is that: having all the game logic code `(main ENTER_FRAME)` in the `Main Class` is better. If you have many `ENTER_FRAMES` you will have many troubles. However if you want to do it this way, follow the steps that I mentioned in the post to fix your game with your current game logic.

Comment: I tried your code but I'm guessing it's glitchy? For some reason my player stops and cannot move when touching the object. I used if(_collision){}. Even if I put nothing inside the code, it makes my character stop.

Comment: I've modified your `FLA` with the code above, but you'll see that a flickering occur. The explanation of this issue is in my comment above. Please, follow my reccomendation and put a single `ENTER_FRAME` for your game logic. [FLA](http://xprimiendo.com/examples/FLASH/Subject.zip)